# How to list all combinations of words?

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a one liner that will achieve something like this (with 2 or more argument strings):

```
$ make_combinations "1 2" "a b c"
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
```

Of course I could make nested for loops, but if there is a generic and fast way to achieve this, it would be better. This would be very useful to use with xargs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf "%s\n" {1,2}" "{a,b,c}
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
```

Or

```
echo {1,2}" "{a,b,c} | xargs -n 2
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
```

As @George Vasiliou mention in his comment when the list can be wriiten as a range you can use it as below:

```
printf '%s\n' {1..2}" "{a..c}
```

Comment: @Afusco -  if my answer solved your question please [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Comment: Working with ranges is better instead of list. Your example if someone wants to extended from a to z would be cumbersome. I suggest to include in your answer the "range" method also : `printf '%s\n' {1..2}" "{a..c}`

Comment: @george - thanks for the comment. Answer was updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function brace {
  first=$1
  first=${first//,/\\\,}
  first=${first//\{/\{}
  first=${first//\}/\\\}}
  if [[ $first =~ [[:space:]] ]]
  then
    first=${first// /,}
    str={"${first}"}
  else
    str="${first}"
  fi
  shift
  for arg
  do
    arg=${arg//,/\\\,}
    arg=${arg//\{/\\{}
    arg=${arg//\}/\\\}}
    if [[ $arg =~ [[:space:]] ]]
    then
      arg=${arg// /,}
      str="${str}"'" "{'"$arg"'}'
    else
      str="${str}"'" "'"${arg}"
    fi
  done
  eval printf '%s\\n' "$str"
}

$ brace } "a b" { "c,d,e f"
} a { c,d,e
} a { f
} b { c,d,e
} b { f
```